# Blender 3.0 did they change the geometry nodes structure?

Tags: geometry-nodes, versions

I've been checking 3.0 alpha builds for a few months already and there appeared one major change in Geometry nodes: all the attribute nodes have gone (except two). I thought it might be just a temporal bug but it hasn't been changed since September (or maybe even earlier). So I wonder is it a new structure? Is there anywhere I can follow and read about the last updates of alpha builds before the official release?

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Nodes_Physics (Improved Attribute Workflow)

Comment: ToT I barely get used to an old structure... Anyways, Thanks for the reply! =]

Answer (score 2):

For all those who missed this new update in Geometry nodes (as did I))
As Brockmann mentioned in the comment above (thanks a lot!) the information can be found by the link https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Nodes_Physics

And here you can take a look at the new process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yci5ouEmnLI